# Compile time error Subtype collection object referenced by super-type collection reference

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors, polymorphism

I have designed my entity classes so that the abstractions can be set in the bases classes since I did not want to repeat same code. However in doing so I have reached a point where I want to have a reference of superclass' generic collection pointing to sub-class typed collection but its spitting out a compiler error. Please refer to the below class skeletons and advise how should I redesign or resolve the issue so that in Test method I do not get any error.

Please NOTE that if your solution is to have it like I've done in baseRef3 then that's not what I want. I want the base collection class reference pointing to typed sub-class collection object.

```
public interface IEntity
{
}

public class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
}

public abstract class BaseEntityCollection<T> : List<T>
    where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
}

public class RealEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

public class RealEntityCollection : BaseEntityCollection<RealEntity>
{
}

public static void Test()
    {
        //Gives compile time error on both of below lines
        BaseEntityCollection<BaseEntity> baseRef1 = new RealEntityCollection();
        BaseEntityCollection<BaseEntity> baseRef2 = (BaseEntityCollection<RealEntity>)(new RealEntityCollection());

        //Following works with RealEntity in the refence but I do not want to keep ref to subtype rather base
        BaseEntityCollection<RealEntity> baseRef3 = new RealEntityCollection();         
    }
```

Thanks

EDIT: I am using .NET 3.5 so not sure if Generics covariance is supported. Any help highly appreciated!

---

I've simplified my design further to following:

```
public interface IEntity
{
}

public class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
}

public class RealEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

public class RealEntityCollection : IEnumerable<RealEntity>
{
}
```

But following two lines are still giving compiler error:

```
IEnumerable<BaseEntity> baseRef1 = new RealEntityCollection();
IEnumerable<IEntity> baseRef2 = new List<RealEntity>();
```

However following two are working:

```
IEnumerable<BaseEntity> baseRef3 = (IEnumerable<BaseEntity>)(new List<RealEntity>());
IEnumerable<IEntity> baseRef4 = (IEnumerable<IEntity>)(new List<RealEntity>());
```

Actually I do not want to have casting as its time consuming so the above two lines that work don't seem ideal. Is there any other way I can get around solving this in .NET 3.5?

Comment: There are tons of questions about this. What you're asking is "Generic Covariance" which is not supported with classes and value types.

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 and if I go with interface then is that going to be supported? How will you recommend redesigned code should look like? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A `BaseEntityCollection<RealEntity>` is NOT a `BaseEntityCollection<BaseEntity>`.  Otherwise you could do this:

```
BaseEntityCollection<BaseEntity> baseRef1 = new RealEntityCollection();
baseRef1.Add(new OtherRealEntity());
```

Unless you change the definition of `BaseEntityCollection<T>` to use a covariant interface like `IEnuemerable<T>` then there's no way to cast/convert/fake the compiler.

Comment: OP confirmed that he's using .Net3.5. I believe covariance is supported from c#4.0 but am not sure whether .Net3.5 supports it  with c#4.0 compiler.